# Python: Interpretation on XCORR

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I have a question on [xcorr](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xcorr) in Python. Say that I do the following:

```
output=plt.xcorr(x,y, maxlags=4)
```

Which time-series is lagged? The output will be the cross-correlation between x and y at time *t=* -4 to +4. So is the output referring to the cross-correlation between x and y as follow?:

[image]
or it is the reverse between x and y?
I tried to dig into the code of xcorr to get a better idea (see [here](http://matplotlib.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.98.3/classmatplotlib_1_1axes_1_1Axes_4f32bd673965a088a123e407b46c42fa.html)) but I am bit lost ... np.correlate(x,y,mode = 2). What does mode = 2 means? I only see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) the mode being = `valid`, `full`, or `same`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `mode` parameter determines what happens near the boundaries. If you have input vectors with length x and y (x > y):

- `valid` / 0: you will only receive the portion of the convolution where both signals overlap (x-y+1 points)
- `same` / 1: the length of the output vector is the same as the length of the longer input vector (x points)
- `full` / 2: all data from the area where there is even a single sample of overlap between the signals (x+y-1 points)

The numbers for these modes are not very publicly defined, byt they can be found in `numpy`'s source code. In any case `xcorr`uses the `full` mode. (Actually, only the first letters of mode names matter when giving the mode for `convolve` or  `correlate`.)

There is some confusion as to what these functions really do. `numpy.correlate` has two different behaviours depending on `numpy` version. Internally these are known as `multiarray.correlate` (old) and `multiarray.correlate2` (new). `numpy.convolve` reverses the second input vector and uses then `multiarray.correlate` (i.e. the one deprecated for correlation).

So, if you want to be really sure, you test what happens. The basic function is the product between two vectors where the vectors are moved one position at a time. To clarify this, I'll use some numeric examples with two vectors.

```
a <= [1,2,3,4,5]
b <= [10,20]
```

let's first look at convolve:

```
numpy.convolve(a,b,mode='full') => [ 10, 40, 70, 100, 230, 100]
```

this is because:

```
    1  2  3  4  5  => 1 x 10 = 10
20 10

    1  2  3  4  5  => 1 x 20 + 2 x 10 = 40
   20 10

...

    1  2  3  4  5     => 5 x 20 = 100
               20 10
```

Different modes return the same data but truncated at each end.

For correlation:

```
numpy.correlate(a,b,mode='full') => [ 20, 50, 80, 110, 140, 50]

    1  2  3  4  5  => 1 x 20 = 20
10 20

    1  2  3  4  5  => 1 x 10 + 2 x 20 = 50
   10 20

...

    1  2  3  4  5     => 5 x 10 = 100
               10 20
```

So, basically the only difference with real numbers is that one of the vectors is mirrored. This has some consequences, such as convolution giving the same result if `a` and `b` is swapped, correlation giving reversed result in that case. With complex numbers `correlate` conjugates the second vector prior to the calculations above.

---

Back to `matplotlib`'s `xcorr` graph. It receives two vectors `x` and `y` with equal lengths and calculates the cross-correlation of these vectors at different lags.

It first calculates the full convolution with `numpy.correlate` between `x` and `y` as shown above. Then it draws the correlation results from the full output vector at positions `-maxlags`..`maxlags`. The rule is that the second input vector is shifted. At the leftmost graph position the second vector `y` is at its leftmost position (i.e. shifted to the left from `x`).

The easiest way to check this may be:

```
xcorr([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.], [0,0,0,0,1.], normed=False, maxlags=4)
```

Comment: Great now I understand the mode in Python but how should I interpret the cross-autocorrelation output? Which of the time-series is lagged?